# EF Core Map to SQL View with Complex Type

Tags: entity-framework, sql-view, ef-core-2.0, ef-core-2.1

I have a SQL View I need to use with EF Core Code First. The view looks something like this (simplified):

```
    Select s.Id                 
           a.City                  
           a.State
    From   Shipment s
           Join Address a
             On s.AddressId = a.Id
```

I want it to Map to a Class POCO of Shipment List View:

```
        public class ShipmentListView
        {
            [Key]
            public int Id { get; set; }

            public Address Address { get; set; }
        }

        public class Address
        {
            public string City { get; set; }
            public string State { get; set; }
        }
```

Db Set:

```
    public virtual DbSet<ShipmentListView> ShipmentListView { get; set; }
```

How do I map the normalized View so I can reuse my `Address` class in the context of my POCO `ShipmentListView`

Answer (score -1):

You can map your model with SQL View as it seems below;

```
 protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
      modelBuilder.Entity<ShipmentListView>(eb =>
        {
          eb.ToView("ShipmentListView");
        });
      base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
```

As for using Related classed for that model, you may use a workaround.

```
    public class ShipmentListView : Address
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public Address Address { get; set; }
    }

    public class Address
    {
        public string City { get; set; }
        public string State { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: The `Address` property wouldn't work anyway right? You would just split it into 2 classes